# where can I find world-wide commercial flight routes information?

Tags: data-request, transportation

I'm looking for a full list of all commercial passenger routes across the world.

Answer (score 0):

Would [Open Flights](http://openflights.org/data.html#route) provide a starting point?

Comment: `Warning: The third-party that OpenFlights uses for route data ceased providing updates in June 2014. The current data is of historical value only.`